# Launch emulator from windows command line receive error G67247B7E

Tags: flutter, vcxproj

Newbee here.  Trying to run the android emulator for the generic first_app flutter application.
Run flutter run -d windows

Receive:
C:\Development\Flutter\first_app>flutter run -d windows
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib/main.dart(60,15): error G67247B7E: Expected ';' after this. [C:\Development\Flutter\first_app\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Development\Flutter\first_app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\13756e3632117b79f6e0bc292bc438e0\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Development\Flutter\first_app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\f154f6c681490929a1ff6491e40cd6b3\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\Development\Flutter\first_app\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...
Exception: Build process failed.

Other information:
Flutter Doctor is clean.  That took hours.
Running from Android Studio works.
Launching emulator works correctly
Have tried Flutter Clean, Flutter upgrade, Flutter Master.
Have tried running from powershell with the same error.

Any assistance welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

First you can check if the emulator is running or not by this command

```
flutter devices
```

Then you can directly run your app through

```
flutter run -d device-id
```

In my case, it was

```
flutter run -d emulator-5554
```

[image: devices]

Comment: Thank you for responding.  
I only have windows, chrome and edge as devices.

C:\Development\Flutter\first_app>flutter devices
3 connected devices:

Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.45
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 108.0.1462.46

Comment: So it means that the emulator was not running,  try to start the emulator first and then perform these commands, hope it'll work

Answer (score 0):

All, on a whim, I deleted my first_app and created it again via flutter create first_app.
Immediately running flutter run, it works!